# dism for a subset of Hyper V features only

Tags: hyper-v, dism

Environment: Mix of Windows 10 and Windows 11

Trying to use dism to enable Hyper V Hypervisor only. Tried:

```
dism /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
```

Complains of need to enable parent feature via an additional `/All` argument. As soon as that is added, everything under Hyper V is enabled. Here is a screenshot of running:

```
dism /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
```

OR running

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

[image: all-hyper-v-features]

What I am really aiming for is this:

[image: desired hyper v features]

How does one make dism enable only the Hypervisor feature ?

Comment: Have you tested [`DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) to see if that does it or does it too install all features?

Comment: Please show what `/All` does.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle, edited this question to include screenshot

Comment: @harrymc, edited this question to include screenshot. For some reason, I ain't allowed to tag more than 1 persons via comments.

Comment: @ParagDoke - You are not supposed to be able to ping multiple users. Simply modifying the question will notify them of the change if they are following the question.

Comment: In order to install the `Hyper-V Hypervisor` you must install both `Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor` and `Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services`.  So why are you trying to avoid installing the required services? `Hyper-V Mangement Tools` which is `Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell` is optional.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for that input. At least on 1 system, I do not have Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services enabled. But I am able to use Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor for WSL2. Led me to believe that only 1 sub-feature serves the purpose. But I cannot get dism to do that for me.

Comment: The requirements for WSL2 and Hyper-V Hypervisor are entirely different.  Are you trying to enable Hyper-V or WSL2? `Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor` nor  `Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services` is not required to install WSL2.  Why don't you just install WSL2 using the suggested method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140332/discussion-between-ramhound-and-parag-doke).